# If I'm uploading video to make a fan video, how do I cut audio from the already existing video?

Tags: windows

If I'm uploading video to make a fan video, how do I cut audio from the already existing video?

Using Windows Live Movie Maker.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried xilisoft video cutter: http://www.xilisoft.com/video-cutter.html